# Is an Extension method similar to having "new" keyword method in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, extension-methods, new-operator

Can we have some relation between extension methods and inheritance?

Or is an extension method similar to using the `new`-keyword in C#?

Comment: Welcome at SO. It might help us if you explain which of the three main meanings of the `new` keyword you refer to: class instantiation (as in `new House()`), method overriding (as in `new public void Activate()` when inheriting a class that contains `Activate` already) or the `new()` generic constraint (as in `where T: new()`).

Comment: method overriding (as in new public  void)

Answer (score 9):

No to both questions. An extension method is actually a method that takes the object the extension operates on as first parameter.

The `new` keyword is used to allocate resources for an instance of a class. An extension method operates on an instance, but cannot act as a new-replacement, simply because it requires an instance (or `null` of that type) as a first parameter.

Consider:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Reverse(this string _this)
    {
        // logic to reverse the string
    }
}
```

You can call this static method in two ways:

```
// as an extension method:
string s = "hello world";
string t = s.Reverse();

// as a static method invocation:
string t = StringExtensions.Reverse(s);
```

In either case, the compiler changes the call in MSIL to map the second call. After compiling, there's no way you would recognize an extension method from it's static counterpart without the `this`-keyword.

**To summarize**

- Extensions are *not* part of the class
- Extensions have no relation to inheritance, in fact they are static methods, which are not inherited
- Extensions *cannot* instantiate classes like the `new` keyword does (but inside the method you can of course instantiate classes).
- Extension *can* operate on `null`, where otherwise a method of that class would raise a `NullReferenceException`. This follows from the fact that the instance is simply the first parameter in the static method.
- It is possible to extend *sealed* classes (like `string` above), which is not possible through inheritance (you cannot derive from sealed classes).

**EDIT:**
Tigran and Floran hinted that this question is about the [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier), and I added it might even be about the [new generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx).

An extension method has *no* relation with either meaning of the `new` keyword. Here are, however, some thoughts in relation to each other. I hope it doesn't confuse matters more. If so, stick to the part above "EDIT" ;)

- On the new modifier:

  - the new modifier is used to hide existing methods. An extension method can *never* hide existing methods, because the declaration is a static method. You will not even get a compile time warning or error when you do.
  - The new modifier requires that the method (or property) already exists and is accessible. An extension method can only work if the method with the same signature does *not* already exist.
  - The new modifier operates on an extension of the class through inheritance, i.e., every method is already inherited. An extension method operates on an instance of the class and has no inheritance relationship with the class.
- On the new generic constraint:

  - the constraint limits the allowed generic types to those with an accessible parameterless constructor. An extension method has nothing to do with generics.
  - an extension method itself van be generic and the parameters (i.e., the allowed classes it operates on) can be limited by the new generic constraint:

    ```
    // this ext. method will only operate on classes that inherit 
    // from ICollectible and have a public parameterless constructor
    public static int CalculateTotal<T>(this T _collectible)
        where T : ICollectible, new()
    {
        // calculate total
    }
    ```

Comment: I would believe that the question is about the [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier), as in habib.osu's reply, rather than the [new operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newoperator). Other than that I agree with your reply.

Comment: `new` was about members shadowing

Comment: @Florin / @Tigran: that is possible, though I don't read that from the question. In that respect, it could've also been about the generic constraint `new()`. Only RDK can shed light on that I guess. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Abel: the thing is that shadowing *can* be easily confused with overloading, but I don't think `new object()` can be confused with OOP concept.

Comment: @Tigran: now you bring overloading to the discussion ;). That's another, yet closely related, angle. Overloading is about different signatures with the same name, while `new` can only hide a method with _exactly_ the same signature. But I agree that it's more likely that the OP means this than what I originally wrote.

Comment: @Abel: pardon Abel, my fault. I mean overriding, just typo... dummy mistake.

Answer (score 3):

No, extension method simply extends the functionality of already existing class.

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type.

See [MSDN on Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

The `new` keyword is needed to allow you to `override` non-virtual and static methods from the base class.

```
public class A
{
   public virtual void One();
   public void Two();
}

public class B : A
{
   public override void One();
   public new void Two();
}

B b = new B();
A a = b as A;

a.One(); // Calls implementation in B
a.Two(); // Calls implementation in A
b.One(); // Calls implementation in B
b.Two(); // Calls implementation in B
```

Check out [this link on `new` vs `override`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/65e02299-300f-4b74-8f0a-679f490605f5).

Comment: _"override non-virtual and static methods from the base class."_  >> no, because static methods are not inherited to begin with, and no, because you can also use `new` on virtual methods, which is slightly different than overriding with `override`.

Answer (score 1):

No. An extension method is syntactic sugar for a separate, static class that takes, as its first argument, an object of the type that is being "extended."  It isn't related to inheritance at all.  The method only has access to the public members of the "extended" class, just like any other class would.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are not related to inheritance or `new` keyword (or constructors). They allow for nicer code if you want to add some functionality to a class you do not have source code for. It also works if you do have the source code but then it is usually better to just change the source code.

For example you might like to be able to do this:

```
string text = "this is my string";
int count = text.WordCount();
```

This method does not exist in the `String` class and you need to do it like that:

```
string text = "this is my string";
int count = MyCommon.WordCount(text);
```

where `WordCount()` is a static method in some sort of common library of yours.

But with the extension methods you can also do this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}
```

and then `text.WordCount()` will work just as if it was normal method defined in the `String` class. It just makes things a bit nicer to use.

Code taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which I suggest to read as well.